# error in mysql while featching interval data why?

Tags: mysql

i did this in mysql

```
Select max(bid) FROM data WHERE realtime BETWEEN (2017-05-11 11:29:00) AND (2017-05-11 11:30:00);
```

i show error as

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '11:29:00) AND (2017-05-11 11:30:00) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: You need single quotes around those timestamps.  Use this:

Comment: `WHERE realtime BETWEEN '2017-05-11 11:29:00' AND '2017-05-11 11:30:00'`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the dates in single quotes

```
Select max(bid) FROM data WHERE realtime BETWEEN ('2017-05-11 11:29:00') AND ('2017-05-11 11:30:00');
```